# How to add an extra-space before a question mark?

Tags: fontspec, adobe

Using Adobe Garamond Pro, I don't get an extra space mark before a question mark. In French, it is absolutely required. Using Word, I don't have the same issue. Should I resolve myself to go back to Word instead of Latex? This is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
    \frenchspacing
    \begin{document}
   Pourquoi faut-il que les Français ajoutent un espace avant un point d'interrogation ?
    \end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me. Is your tex system up-to-date? Do you use lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: You can use `~` for a non-breaking space, i.e., it will treat `d'interrogation~?` as `d'int-erro-gation ?` (assuming I got the hyphenation correct).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Are you sure that the visible space is the right one? I use Xelatex.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSDG6.png . The first two are with french (with and without a space in the input), the two other same input with the german language.  I get the same with lualatex and xelatex on a current texlive.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The third is the one I must have. I've just tried with  \usepackage[german]{babel} and it works... How could I fix it?

Comment: @domi german is doing nothing  you just get a normal word space if you add a space, the french option does not require you to add a space and ignores one if added and always inserts a (thin, non breakable) space in accordance with some versions of french typographic tradition.

Comment: you certainly don't want to use ngerman for a french text. To change the spacing search the  documentation of babel-french for \FBsetspaces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: you're right : it's a thin and non breakable space that inserts adobe Garamond Pro while using Tex. With Word, the space inserted is non thin and already non breakable.

Comment: as Ulrike says you can set the length babel-french inserts to an arbitrary amount, see `texdoc babel-french`

Comment: I don't see anything in the Babel documentation that could allow me to set an arbitrary amount of space, but as the space before a question mark is in principle a thin and non breakable space, then, it's good.